# Query firestore collection and expect an array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to query a collection of users, and would like to get an array of just firebase uids ['uid1','uid2'], but the result is undefined

My query

```
const id = admin.firestore().collection('users').get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
```

Comment: Is either of the `console.log` statements printed?

Comment: yes, it's just getting all the information from the document like documentId1 = [field1, field2], I think I need some advice on how to cut just ids from there and create an array

Comment: uploaded the screenshot with log results https://paste.pics/c476f203e0f19f4df2ba69c76ffc2053

Comment: I can't really tell anything at all in that screenshot.  Could you update the question to more clearly describe what you're trying to do, the types of document fields you're working with, and anything specific that isn't working the way you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an array with just the document IDs, you can do:

```
admin.firestore().collection('users').get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        let ids = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            ids.push(doc.id);
        });
        console.log(ids);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
```

But note that `ids` is only going to be available/populated within the `then()` callback, since data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously.

---

If you want to use `ids` outside of the callback, you can consider the more modern `async`/`await` construct of JavaScript. In that case you could do:

```
let ids = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        let ids = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            ids.push(doc.id);
        });
        return ids;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
console.log(ids);
```

Or the (in my opinion) slightly more readable:

```
let querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').get();

let ids = querySnapshot.map((doc) => doc.id);

console.log(ids);
```